# Click button cause multiple function calls

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtgui, qt-signals

I develop a python program. The following code is my program. The problem is when I click self.ui.Restart_Btn which call self.restartClicked() method and I click self.ui.B11, it call the method self.boardClicked() twice (which it should call only one time). Moreover, it will repeatedly call 3, 4, 5, ... times after I click self.ui.Restart_Btn 3rd, 4th, 5th, ... times and click self.ui.B11

I don't know what happen with my program.

```
 from MainWin import Ui_MainWindow
 from WelcomDialog import Ui_Dialog

 class iCheckers(QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self, parent = None):
         super(iCheckers, self).__init__(parent)
         self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
         self.ui.setupUi(self)

         # Attribute
         self.buttonArr = [  [self.ui.B11, self.ui.B12, self.ui.B13, self.ui.B14, self.ui.B15, self.ui.B16, self.ui.B17, self.ui.B18],
                             [self.ui.B21, self.ui.B22, self.ui.B23, self.ui.B24, self.ui.B25, self.ui.B26, self.ui.B27, self.ui.B28],
                             [self.ui.B31, self.ui.B32, self.ui.B33, self.ui.B34, self.ui.B35, self.ui.B36, self.ui.B37, self.ui.B38],
                             [self.ui.B41, self.ui.B42, self.ui.B43, self.ui.B44, self.ui.B45, self.ui.B46, self.ui.B47, self.ui.B48],
                             [self.ui.B51, self.ui.B52, self.ui.B53, self.ui.B54, self.ui.B55, self.ui.B56, self.ui.B57, self.ui.B58],
                             [self.ui.B61, self.ui.B62, self.ui.B63, self.ui.B64, self.ui.B65, self.ui.B66, self.ui.B67, self.ui.B68],
                             [self.ui.B71, self.ui.B72, self.ui.B73, self.ui.B74, self.ui.B75, self.ui.B76, self.ui.B77, self.ui.B78],
                             [self.ui.B81, self.ui.B82, self.ui.B83, self.ui.B84, self.ui.B85, self.ui.B86, self.ui.B87, self.ui.B88] ] 
         self.clicked_button = None
         self.turn = 0;  # 0 = Player, 1 = Computer
         self.computer_score = 0
         self.player_score = 0

         self.update_mainWin()
         self.init_board()
         self.init_dialog()
         self.show()   

     def init_dialog(self):
         self.dialog = QDialog()
         self.dialog.ui = Ui_Dialog()
         self.dialog.ui.setupUi(self.dialog)
         #self.dialog.show()

         self.dialog.ui.Player_first_Btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.start, 0))
         self.dialog.ui.Computer_first_Btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.start, 1))

     def start(self, firstPlayer):
         # firstPlayer = 0 >> Player Starts
         # firstPlayer = 1 >> Player Starts

         if firstPlayer == 0:
             self.turn = 0;
             print("Player Start!!")
         elif firstPlayer == 1:
             self.turn = 1;
             print("Computer Start!!")
         self.init_board()
         self.boardClicked(True)
         self.update_mainWin()
         self.dialog.hide()

     def init_board(self):
         self.board = [[0 for x in range(8)] for x in range(8)] 

         # Init Computer Piece
         for i in range(1,24,2):
             row = int(math.ceil( i/8 ))
             column = i%8
             if row % 2 == 1:
                 column -= 1
             self.board[row][column] = 2

         # Init Player Piece
         for i in range(41,64,2):
             row = int(math.ceil( i/8 ))
             column = i%8
             if row % 2 == 1:
                 column -= 1
             self.board[row][column] = 1

         # Init White Box
         for i in range(1,64,2):
            row = int(math.ceil( i/8 ))
            column = i%8
            if row % 2 == 0:
                column -= 1
            self.board[row][column] = -1


     def update_mainWin(self):
         # Update Turn
         self.updateTurn()

         # Initial Score Board
         self.updateScore()

         # Initial Restart Button
         self.ui.Restart_Btn.clicked.connect(self.restartClicked)

         # Initial Board Button
         self.initBoardBtn()

     def initBoardBtn(self):
         for i in range(0, 8):
             for j in range(0, 8):
                 self.buttonArr[i][j].clicked.connect(self.boardClicked)

     def boardClicked(self, reset = False):
         sender = self.sender()
         if self.clicked_button != None:
             button_name = self.clicked_button.objectName()
             button_nameArr = list(button_name)
             row = int(button_nameArr[1])-1;
             column = int(button_nameArr[2])-1;

             if self.board[row][column] == 0:
                 self.clicked_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #383838;")
             elif self.board[row][column] == 1:
                 self.clicked_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #383838;background-image: url(:/image/Red_Pieces.png);")
             elif self.board[row][column] == 2:
                 self.clicked_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #383838;background-image: url(:/image/Black_Pieces.png);")
             elif self.board[row][column] == 3:
                 self.clicked_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #383838;background-image: url(:/image/Red_King.png);")
             elif self.board[row][column] == 4:
                 self.clicked_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #383838;background-image: url(:/image/Black_King.png);")

         if reset:
             self.clicked_button = None
             return

         self.clicked_button = sender
         button_name = self.clicked_button.objectName()
         button_nameArr = list(button_name)
         row = int(button_nameArr[1])-1;
         column = int(button_nameArr[2])-1;
         if self.board[row][column] == 0:
             self.clicked_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #707070;")
         elif self.board[row][column] == 1:
             self.clicked_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #707070;background-image: url(:/image/Red_Pieces.png);")
         elif self.board[row][column] == 2:
             self.clicked_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #707070;background-image: url(:/image/Black_Pieces.png);")
         elif self.board[row][column] == 3:
             self.clicked_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #707070;background-image: url(:/image/Red_King.png);")
         elif self.board[row][column] == 4:
             self.clicked_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #707070;background-image: url(:/image/Black_King.png);")
         print("Board: " + sender.objectName());

     def restartClicked(self):
         print("Restart!")
         self.dialog.show()
         # self.init_dialog()

     def updateTurn(self):
         if self.turn == 0:
             self.ui.Turn_img.setStyleSheet("background-color: #909090;background-image: url(:/image/Red_Icon.png);")
         elif self.turn == 1:
             self.ui.Turn_img.setStyleSheet("background-color: #909090;background-image: url(:/image/Black_Icon.png);")

     def updateScore(self):
         self.ui.Computer_Score_label.setText(str(self.computer_score))
         self.ui.Player_Score_label.setText(str(self.player_score))

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     window = iCheckers()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why don't you throw out the irrelevant parts of your code to provide an SSCCE? Also, are you sure that it is a good idea to connect in `update_mainWin`? That sounds like a method that is called from time to time, in which case, you should not connect so. You either disconnect or connect where the rest is.

Comment: I just seen that I connect multiple times. Thank you! @lpapp

Comment: Well, if the issue is resolved by an answer, please select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is relatively straight-forward, you misunderstand how connect works in Qt.

You seem to be connecting signals to slots at each invocation of certain methods. That seems to be conflicting with what you (rightfully) want.

You have a workaround and a solution for this problem.

#### Workaround

Use unique connection (`type=Qt.UniqueConnection`).

#### Solution

Move these connect calls to the initialization phase or at least disconnect them before reconnecting. The former is the general practice, but your mileage may vary.